# Iterating through a zip file available on a web url

Tags: python, zip

There is a huge zip file of images available on a url. I want to unzip and access the images one or a batch at a time without first downloading the whole zip file. Is that possible?

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: https://datasets.figure-eight.com/figure_eight_datasets/open-images/test_challenge.zip

Comment: I think this may be difficult.  Play around with `resp = requests.get(url, stream=True); it = resp.iter_content(1)`.  Each time you call `next(it)`, you get a  single byte.  You could look for `b'\x1a'` or some other character that denotes a "separation" between files.  But ZIP files have a lot of "metadata" contained in their byte stream and you may need to parse that out too.  (See examples from [zipfile](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/zipfile.py))